# How to exclude Product Category ID from Shortcode Hook inside functions.php - WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to exclude/disable a shortcode that I've added to the Single Product Template of woocommerce for specific product categories.

The code in functions.php is this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sizeguidemen', 20 );
 
function sizeguidemen() {
    echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="66083"]');
}
```

How can we exclude/disable the shortcode for specific product categories?

I believe it should be something with `array( 'product_cat', '65' );`?

I'm new to php and trying to do it, but doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional logic allows you to run your functions only when certain criteria is met.

In your case, you're looking at the single product page and need to run a function only when category is 'whatever ID'.

By looking at [WooCommerce Conditional Logic – Tags, Examples & PHP](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-conditional-logic-ultimate-php-guide/) tutorial, and specifically at the "PHP: do something if product belongs to a category" section, your code would become the following, where "123" is the category ID you want that to work for:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sizeguidemen', 20 );
 
function sizeguidemen() {
    if ( has_term( 123, 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="66083"]');
    }
}
```

You can even use category "slug" instead of "123", and also an array of these e.g. [123, 456, 789] or ['tables', 'chairs']

Comment: Hi!

Thank you so much!!

The issue however is that I have child category 'Accessories' which is also included in parent 'MEN'. So if I use the provided code from you and has_term is the parent category - it also shows on child categories.

This is why I was looking for a way to 'exclude' or NOT IN some kind of function where I can point specific sub-categories. 

Would this be possible? 

By the way, I am an extreme fan of yours. I have learnt so much from your website, it is absolutely amazing. I am currently using the Shoptimizer theme and you have been a crucial part of it all.

Comment: Thank you! Can you not put the child category inside has_term() instead?

Comment: Hi!

I am not putting the ID inside. I have products which have for example the following category: Men, Men Accessories, Accessories - I only want to disable the hook on 'Accessories' but keep it for Men and Men Accessories. 

I tried putting only Men and Men Accessories ID in the has_term() but it still shows on Accessories. 

Maybe I am doing something wrong. Anyway, I appreciate so much your help here on StackOverflow!

Comment: Still not clear, sorry :| Your code is for the single product page. You can check if the current product belongs to Accessories and if yes, return the shortcode. If you wish to do the other way around, simply use the "!" sign in front of has_term() so that would negate it

Comment: Worked like a charm! 

I managed to exclude specific product categories by adding the ! in front of has_term()

Thank you for the knowledge, you fixed my day!

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :)